# Pattern Matching using Like in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, database

I have a column in my table which has values such as

```
 1VT34
 5AB37-A
 1XY38-2
 0VT31-2
 Science
 History01
 111111
```

I want to fetch only those values which are of the format such that they are alphanumeric, they start with a number ( from 1 to any number ) they should end with a number, if any number has '-' with it then it should be in this format -> 1VT37-A,1VT38-2. The character after '-' can be either any digit from 1-9 or it should be A.

From the above values I want my query to fetch only

```
 1VT34
 5AB37-A
 1XY38-2
```

I have written the following query using like operator -

```
 select * from Details where Name like '[^0A-Z]%'
```

but it also fetches 111111 also which I don't want.

then I wrote this to fetch only alphanumerics

```
   select * from Details where Name like '[^0A-Z]%' and Name like '[^0-9]'
```

but it doesn't fetch anything.

For fetching name with '-', I wrote the following one

```
  select * from Details where Name like '[^0A-Z]%' and (Name like '%-A' or Name like '%-[0-9]')
```

but it only fetched

```
   5AB37-A
   1XY38-2
```

and not others.

To avoid this I used another query using UNION -

```
  select * from Details where Name like '[^0A-Z]%' union 

  select * from Details where Name like '[^0A-Z]%' and Name like '%-A'
```

but 111111 is still getting fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sample data the pattern should be:

```
where Name like '[1-9]%[A-Z]%[A1-9]'
```

or:

```
Name like '[1-9]%[A-Z]%[1-9]' OR Name like '[1-9]%[A-Z]%-[A1-9]'
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e2a5abde0a48f70b385797965a18cbee).
Results:

```
Name
-------
1VT34
5AB37-A
1XY38-2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot. The second option also avoided the use of union thus making my query short and effective.

Answer (score 1):

Getting exact matches using SQL Server is quite tricky.  For correctness, you might consider names like:

```
1VT34$$
1VT34-1-1
```

And other weirdnesses.  So, based on your description:

> I want to fetch only those values which are of the format such that they are alphanumeric, they start with a number ( from 1 to any number ) they should end with a number, if any number has '-' with it then it should be in this format -> 1VT37-A,1VT38-2. The character after '-' can be either any digit from 1-9 or it should be A.

```
where name not like '%[^-a-zA-Z0-9]%' and  -- only alphanumeric and hyphen
      name like '[0-9]%' and               -- starts with a digit
      name not like '%-%-%' and            -- at most one hyphen
      ( (name like '%[0-9]' and name not like '%-%') or  -- ends with a number if no hyphen
        name like '%-[A1-9]'                             -- other ends with hyphen and A or 1-9
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select * from Details where Name like '[1-9][A-Z]%'
```

Comment: Edited my question, the name should not  necessarily contain VT. It can be anything.

Comment: @Anonymous, I've updated my answer - you can give a try